# How to use moment.js with a german locale?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to format a date into german locale with moment.js, Version 2.11.0:

```
var moment = require('moment');
moment.locale("de");

console.log(moment(new Date()).locale('de').format('L'));
console.log(moment(new Date()).locale('de_DE').format('L'));
```

The response remains in english format:

> 01/05/2016
>
> 01/05/2016

Also, the following code should return something in french:

```
var moment = require('moment');
moment.locale('fr');
console.log( moment(1316116057189).fromNow() );
```

> il y a une heure

But it prints:

> 4 years ago

I followed the instructions on the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/). But either they are wrong or i misunderstood... Anyhow, the locale-method isn't working as expected. I installed moment with npm into an react native project. It contains lots of locale-files under a subdirectory. So, missing files could not be the root cause of this issue.

**Update:**

According to the comments, changing the require-statement to this one will work:

```
var moment = require('moment/min/moment-with-locales.js');
```

Comment: What do you think the german **short** date format is?

Comment: this would be "05.01.2016"

Comment: There is the locale formatting option, but this will not calculate the offset with the local machine time..

Comment: I'm going to assume you have the `moment locales.js` ?

Comment: i use require js. And yes, in node_modules is a buch of localfiles from momentjs

Comment: right, and you're sure require is using them ? Also RE : http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: @xkcd149 This is no duplicate. I considered your link before asking by myself. The solution printed there isnt working either

Comment: @Pogrindis: no, i'm not sure...  i'm just the consumer of a library and expect that it will work as documented :)

Comment: Can you provide an example replicating the issue with jsbin?

Comment: should work, see https://jsfiddle.net/18ve6hzd/ maybe you don't load the locale files (from the doc: "If there is a locale file in moment-root/locale/ named after that key", key being "de" or "fr" here)

Comment: Chaning the require statement to this one will work: var moment = require('moment/min/moment-with-locales.js');